# Recuperar HTML atualizado por javascript usando DOM

Tags: php

Tem alguma forma de recuperar um HTML atualizado usando DOM?
A Página HTML original é de um site remoto, que não tenho acesso interno, e é assim:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
        loading
</div>
```

Quando clicamos em um botão dentro da página, o `javascript` age, e a `div` é modifica, ficando algo como:

```
<div class="content" id="content">
            <span class="values">text1</span>
            <span class="values">text2</span>
    </div>
```

Eu preciso recuperar os textos das tags `<span>`, que no caso foi o `javascript` quem o inseriu. Usei DOM:

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://sitetal.com");
$DOM =  new DOMDocument();
$DOM->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($DOM);
$span = $xpath->query('//*[contains(concat(" ", normalize-space(@class), " "), "values")]');
foreach($span as $spanvalue){
    $sp = floatval($spanvalue[0]->nodeValue);
    $spaValue = $sp;

echo $spaValue;
}
```

Mas obviamente nada me é retornado, pois o `<span>` ainda não foi criado, ele só será criado quando for clicado no botão lá do site, e o `javascript` inserir a informação. há alguma maneira de recuperar o HTML atualizado, pra ler os valores que foi gerado na `<span>` ?
Pra mim recuperar o text 1 e text 2.?

Answer (score 1):

A resposta curta e grossa é **não, não é possível simular comportamento do usuário com requisições em PHP**.

Comportamentos do usuário só podem ser feitos através de `Javascript` e é necessário um interpretador, no caso os navegadores possuem um.

Quando você envia uma requisição em PHP, só está requisitando `dados`, não é possível emular comportamentos em cima desses dados.

Comment: Então, qual seria a solução pra mim resgatar esses dados clicados?
Lembrando que não sou o programador do site original, eu só posso inserir códigos nele por um parser que fiz.
Você conhece alguma forma de passar tal valores pra mim poder trata-los dele posteriormente?